# End user cookie consent Management for Communities

Tags: lightning-community, cookies

As per the below link, since Salesforce does not currently provide out-of-the-box functionality for end-user cookie consent management in Lightning Communities, please suggest any third-party solution compatible with Salesforce, which displays the cookie banner for end users  to accept or drop cookies.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351913&type=1&mode=1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Force.com labs [Community Cookie consent](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G11jcUAB). It is free and configurable. We have implemented this in our community and it works well.

Major features are:

- Browser unique id tracking
- Creates Individual object records and tags status of cookies.
- Different type of cookie and message configuration like functional performance etc.

Comment: Thanks, I see there is no support provided . Is there any any other recommendation please.

Comment: @Manjit5190 We implemented this and but the description of the cookies is not showing up. The Cookie name is coming up though. The profile has read/edit access to all the objects from the app. Any idea what might be causing this issue??